# Finding the App Store page for an installed app

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I have this app that hasn't been updated for a while and when I search for it in the App Store, all that comes up are similar apps or at best the same app, but the version specifically for iPad. It's not a question of country. The app still works in iOS 14.

How can I find the specific App Store page for an installed app in iOS without just searching and facing these drawbacks?:

- having to wade through result lists
- not really be sure I've actually found the right page
- potentially, not even finding the app at all

I posted my own answer as I stumbled upon a solution, but if you know another way with other benefits, please post that. This would include if this works differently in other versions of iOS as well.

Answer (score 2):

This works at least in iOS 14:

1. Open the App Store app.
2. Go to your App Store user account. Currently in iOS 14, this resides in the upper right and the symbol for your user on your device.
3. Select "Purchases", then "My purchases".
4. Enter the name of your app in the search field, or if you have few apps in your account just scroll down if needed and look for it.
5. Make sure the app is one you got installed by looking to the right of it in the list. If there is a download symbol there, it's not currently installed. If it says "open" in the same place, it is installed.
6. Hold down on the app in this list and a quick preview page will pop up.
7. To get the actual page just tap in the quick preview page.

The benefit over just searching the App Store is that you can know you've found the correct app and not one that has a similar name or is another alternative or variant from the developer. Possibly it might also show apps that aren't listed under the developer name, but that still has its page in the store.

I couldn't find the info for this question when searching, then stumbled on a solution tapping around, so posted this for anyone else needing to know.

Comment: Can't you get the same result by just searching for the app? You'll see the download/installation status also there.

Comment: While that's an alternative I don't feel this satisfies the requirement to really be sure you've found the page for the specific app. You have to be able to find it by search and I've found you far too often get not the results you expect. Also you'd have to wade through results, if there are many closely named apps.

Comment: In addition, what was behind this question for me was an app that I cannot find in App Store for my iPhone (only for iPad, which is another version), but the app still works in iOS 14 and has a page that can be found this way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Hold on the app icon of your choice
2. Select "Share App"
3. In the share sheet, select "Copy link"
4. Open Safari
5. Paste to Safari address bar and go

There you go. App Store page will pop up right away.

This should work in all modern iOS versions (iOS 12+).

Comment: Of course, the app needs to be installed, which might not always be the case, but when it is this might be the quickest way. Somewhat surprising you cannot share directly to Safari though. Apple…